# Memory layout of dynamic loaded/linked library

Tags: linux, c, dynamic-linking, elf, shared-memory

when loading a shared library in Linux system, what is the memory layout of the shared library?

For instance, the original memory layout is the following:

```
+-----------+
|heap(ori)  |
+-----------+
|stack(ori) |
+-----------+
|.data(ori) |
+-----------+
|.text(ori) |
+-----------+
```

When I dlopen `foo.so`, will the memory layout be A or B?

```
A
+-----------+
|heap(ori)  |
+-----------+
|stack(ori) |
+-----------+
|.data(ori) |
+-----------+
|.text(ori) |
+-----------+
|heap(foo)  |
+-----------+
|stack(foo) |
+-----------+
|.data(foo) |
+-----------+
|.text(foo) |
+-----------+
```

Or

```
B
+-----------+
|heap(ori)  |
+-----------+
|heap(foo)  |
+-----------+
|stack(foo) |
+-----------+
|stack(ori) |
+-----------+
|.data(foo) |
+-----------+
|.data(ori) |
+-----------+
|.text(foo) |
+-----------+
|.text(ori) |
+-----------+
```

Or anything other than A and B... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is "Other".  You can get a glimpse of the memory layout with `cat /proc/self/maps`.  On my 64-bit Arch laptop::

```
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1186758                            /usr/bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 08:02 1186758                            /usr/bin/cat
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:02 1186758                            /usr/bin/cat
02598000-025b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fe4b805c000-7fe4b81f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1182914                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fe4b81f5000-7fe4b83f5000 ---p 00199000 08:02 1182914                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fe4b83f5000-7fe4b83f9000 r--p 00199000 08:02 1182914                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fe4b83f9000-7fe4b83fb000 rw-p 0019d000 08:02 1182914                    /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so
7fe4b83fb000-7fe4b83ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe4b83ff000-7fe4b8421000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1183072                    /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7fe4b85f9000-7fe4b85fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe4b85fe000-7fe4b8620000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe4b8620000-7fe4b8621000 r--p 00021000 08:02 1183072                    /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7fe4b8621000-7fe4b8622000 rw-p 00022000 08:02 1183072                    /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so
7fe4b8622000-7fe4b8623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffe430c4000-7ffe430e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe431ed000-7ffe431ef000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

You can see that the executable gets loaded in low memory, apparently .text segment, read-only data, and .bss. Just about that is "heap". In much higher memory the C library and the "ELF file interpreter", "ld-so" get loaded. Then comes the stack. There's only one stack and one heap for any given address space, no matter how many shared libraries get loaded. `cat` only seems to get the C library loaded.

Doing `cat /proc/$$/maps` will get you the memory mappings of the shell from which you invoked `cat`. Any shell is going to have a number of dynamically loaded libraries, but `zsh` and `bash` will load in a large number. You'll see that there's just one "[heap]", and one "[stack]".

If you call `dlopen()`, the shared object file will get mapped in the address space at a higher address than `/usr/lib/libc-2.21.so`. There's something of an "implementation dependent" memory mapping segment, where all addresses returned by `mmap()` show up. See [Anatomy of a Program in Memory](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/) for a nice graphic.

The source for `/usr/lib/ld-2.21.so` is a bit tricky, but it shares a good deal of its internals with `dlopen()`. `dlopen()` isn't a second class citizen.

"vdso" and "vsyscall" are somewhat mysterious, but [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938324/what-are-vdso-and-vsyscall) has a good explanation, as does Wikipedia.